# How to get the core part - that does the trick - of parallax work?

Tags: javascript, parallax

I tried to experiment with parallax and started from scratch to understand the core parts of this magic. To give you an example that I like to use as inspiration, you can see it [at this link here](http://www.oxfordhouse.nl/about#photos) at the "Photos" section.

***Latest code is down the page with related information. To get an overall look of the question see the rest of the details.***

Core parts I already know are the `scrollTop()` of the `$window` and the `offsetTop` of the element are important to apply the parallax effect on a DOM element as well as a `factor` for how sensitive the effect should be respond to the scroll speed. The end result should be some formule that will calculate the `translateY` or `translate3d` coordinates in pixels or percentage.

I read on the internet that the CSS property `translate` is faster than, for example, `top` from `position: absolute`, and my preference would be also to use translate in combination with [TweenMax GSAP](https://greensock.com/tweenmax). So the movement of the parallax will be very smooth. But if only the css property `translate` is enough that's fine too. I saw some examples that where using TweenMax, so that's why I use it for now.

**JS**

I have code the basic things:

```
var win = $(window);
var el = $('#daily .entry').find('figure');

win.scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();
  var parallaxFactor = 5;

  el.each(function() {
    var image = $(this).find('img');
    var offsetTop = $(this).offset().top;

    // This is the part where I am talking about. 
    // Here should be the magic happen...

  });
});
```

So I've code above code, but it doesn't do anything, of course. [See CodePen from above code here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjNXWj?editors=1111). It will only console log `scrollTop` and `offsetTop`. As mentioned before, I only know the core parts like `scrollTop` and `offsetTop` to apply the parallax effect. Then there should be some area created where the parallax effect will be triggered and happen, so calculations will be only done for elements within the viewport in order to keep the performance good. After that there should be some math done, but doesn't know exactly what or how to achieve this. Only after I have a final number, I could use it within for example `TweenMax` from Greensock like so:

**TweenMax**

```
TweenMax.to(image, 0.1, {
    yPercent: offsetPercent + '%',
    ease: Linear.easeNone
});
```

**Parallax formula**

If I look around to get the formula down I came to something like this (founded on the internet):

```
var viewportOffset = scrollTop - offsetTop + win.height();
var offsetPercent = ((viewportOffset / win.height() * 100) - 100) / parallaxFactor;

if (viewportOffset >= 0 && viewportOffset <= win.height() * 2) {
    TweenMax.to(image, 0.1, {
        yPercent: offsetPercent + '%',
        ease: Linear.easeNone
    });
}
```

But if I am honest, I doesn't know what this does exactly, or why it should/could be this way. I would like to know this, so I can understand the whole process of making parallax happen. The functions of `scrollTop()`, `offsetTop` and `$(window).height()` are clear for me, but what the trick behind the formula is, is the part that I doesn't understand.

### Updates

**Update 1**

@Scott has notified that the inspiration site uses a plugin called [scrollmagic.io](http://scrollmagic.io), but I am very curious about how I can create a parallax by myself without the use of a plugin. How it works and how to achieve it. With emphasis on the formula, why I should it do this or that way and what exactly will be calculated, because I don't understand it and really wanna know this, so that I can use this knowledge in the future when applying a parallax effect.

**Update 2**

I tried to figure out what the following code snippet exactly does. I talking about this one:

```
var viewportOffset = scrollTop - offsetTop + win.height();
```

After some good debug sessions I think that I've the clue. So `scrollTop` is the amount of pixels that you've scrolled down the page and that are hidden from the view. `offsetTop` is the start position of the element within the DOM and `$(window).height` is the viewport height - the part that is visible in the browser -.

This is what I think that this formula does:

Set the zero point to the point where the element starts. For example, when `scrollTop` is equal to 0 and the element starts at `240px` from the top, then the formula is: 0 minus 240 is `-240`. So the current scroll position is below zero point. After scrolling 240px down, the formula will output 0 because of course 240 minus 240 is `0` (zero). Am I right?

But the part that I doesn't understand yet is why `+ win.height`. 
If we go back to above formula (at Update 2) and scrollTop is zero then the `$(window).height` is the space from 240px till the bottom of the viewport. When scrolling down, the amount of pixel will grow on scroll, that makes no sense to me. If someone can explain what could have been the purpose of this would be fine. 'm very curious. The second part of the formula to calculate the parallax `offsetPercent` I still don't understand. In general the calculation of the parallax strength on scroll.

**Update 3 / 4**

Advised by @Edisoni, I walked the last few days [by the videos of Travis Neilson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTZpNAbz3jg) and I have become a lot wiser on the basic functionalities of parallax. A must for everyone who wants to dig in parallax. I've used the new knowledge about parallax to get my above script work:

```
var root = this;
var win = $(window);
var offset = 0;

var elements = $('#daily .entry figure');

if (win.width() >= 768) {
    win.scroll(function() {

        // Get current scroll position
        var scrollPos = win.scrollTop();
        console.log(scrollPos);

        elements.each(function(i) {
            var elem = $(this);
            var triggerElement = elem.offset().top;
            var elemHeight = elem.height();
            var animElem = elem.find('img');

            if (scrollPos > triggerElement - (elemHeight / 2) && scrollPos < triggerElement + elemHeight + (elemHeight / 2)) {
                // Do the magic
                TweenMax.to(animElem, 0.1, {
                    yPercent: -(scrollPos - elemHeight / 2) / 100, 
                    ease: Linear.easeNone
                });

            } else {
                return false;
            }

        });

    });

}
```

However, the script works only for a certain part of the elements. The problem is that it only works for the first two elements. I have a suspicion that the "error" is located in particularly after the AND `&&` sign in the if statement, but can't get the error solved. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKwBAB

When the elements, that work on the trigger are animated, they will be jumping some pixels to the bottom, don't know how to fix this to. 
The jumping to: `1.135%`, after the trigger is fired. So it doesn't start at 0%. I already checked if I should add the CSS property `translate` to the CSS and set the type of number to `%`, but this doesn't work for me.

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
-moz-transform: translateY(0%);
-o-transform: translateY(0%);
transform: translateY(0%);
```

Should I use the `TweenMax` `.fromTo()` function instead of using the `.to()` function so I can set the start position as well or is my thought about this wrong and has a different cause?

Something like this:

```
TweenMax.fromTo(animElem, 0.1, {
    yPercent: triggerElement,
    z: 1
}, {
    yPercent: -(scrollPos - elemHeight / 2) / 100,
    ease: Linear.easeNone
});
```

Beside that I trying to recreate the effect of the site that I would like to use as inspiration source without the use of the scrollMagic plugin, but I don't really know how this works, with the use of two different objects that are animated.

At last, if someone thinks the code can be better formatted, don't hesitate, I would like to hear your suggestions

**My actual questions are for update 2 and 3/4:**

1. How to calculate the parallax y coordinates to get "the magic" done?
2. Am I right about update 2, that the zero point will be reset to offsetTop of each element?
3. Why my code only works for the first two elements and why they jumping some pixels down if the inline style of `translate` will be added to the animated element? See update 3/4 for all info.

Comment: You realize that inspiration site you linked to is merely using http://scrollmagic.io/ right?

Comment: No, I wasn't realize that Scott. Thanks for notifying me. But If there is a possibility to explain the core part of the parallax effect so I understand the parallax and the code in the summary would be really nice. @Scott

Comment: This is what you need for a good starting. He explains very good the way how he does it work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTZpNAbz3jg check this out

Comment: While not explaining how to make *your* code work, this is a fantastic tutorial : http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Comment: @edisoni.1337 Thank you. I will go through the video first!

Comment: What's your *actual, specific* question? Why are you including a big library like GSAP if you're looking to only have "the core? What have you tried for "the magic" section of your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285146/horizontal-parallax-scrolling-from-scratch-no-plugin-jquery Something to check out

Comment: @ZachSaucier I've update my question with your questions too. Sorry if that was not entirely clear for everyone. For GSAP I saw some examples that uses the TweenMax library, so I just tried with that too, so maybe I make it myself for know a little hard.. Hopefully you have something about the added information.

Comment: @Caspert here you have a great free course regarding scrollmagic.io: https://ihatetomatoes.net/product/scrollmagic-101/  Petr really explains very well how things work. Unfortunately I don't have time now to study well your question.

Comment: @BogdanLungu Thank you for the link. I will go through the videos if I can loggin (some trouble with it). But I would like to create it without a plugin, so I understand the parallax in general. If you have some time left, it would be nice if you can help me.

Comment: I don't see any parallax effect in your codepen examples. Parallax effect is when objects closer to you moves slower than those further away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parallax is actually quite simple in principle. Just make the parallax element scroll slower than the rest of the content. That being said, a parallax implementation can be as simple as dividing the scroll distance by a factor:

```
var parallaxFactor = 3;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e){
    el.style.top = (document.body.scrollTop / parallaxFactor) + "px"; 
    // This is the magic. This positions the element's y-cord based off of the page scroll
}, false);
```

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/FelisPhasma/pen/amozgv)

This is an extremely simple demonstration of the parallax effect. Other more thorough implementations may handle values as percentages, or attempt to smooth the animation with TweenMax. This however, is the magic you're looking for.

Live long and prosper.

**Update:**

This example only works for elements at the top of a screen. If this were for a more general purpose, you would want to store the default y-position of the element, then something along the lines of `defaultYCord + (document.body.scrollTop / parallaxFactor)`.

**Update 2:**

A very good visualization for parallax comes from Keith Clark who made a pure css parallax scroller: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/. If you click debug in the upper left, it gives you a nice 3d-view of the magic.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer how to build a parallax in JS. But it shows some basics, which will often be forgotten, if your too much into the code.

#### Basics:

1. Order your graphical objects in z-layers. As higher z is, as nearer
   it is to observer in front of the screen.
2. As higher your object is in the z-axis as faster it should move on something that appears, f.e. your scrolling
3. Now you get a 3-D-Effect where objects nearer to you move faster to your actions as objects more far away.

#### Your question

*How to calculate the parallax y coordinates to get "the magic" done?*

The y-position depends on your z-index. If it is far away a.k.a the z-index is low, delta-y is small. If it is near too you, delta-y is big.
Please consider the z-index is not necessarily used as Style-property, it's more like it looks like. 
I would add an attribute like data-z to every parallaxing layer.

```
function parallaxingY(el){
   //el is a parallaxing element with attribute data-z
   return $(el).data('z')*window.scrollTop;
}
```

the suggested CSS-Solution is nice and should be preferred. There the "magic" - the "z-index" - is made by the css-style "scale".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He is trying to do this with JavaScript.